# Can I deduct equipment that I'm required to purchase by my employer?

Tags: taxes, employment, tax-deduction, united-states

If my employer requires that I own a laptop and other computer equipment, but does not provide them, am I able to deduct the expense of purchasing the equipment? I know that I definitely would deduct these expenses if I was self-employed.

Comment: Good question, but are you asking about U.S.?  Canada?  Tax questions are country-specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can.  Take a look at these articles:

http://www.googobits.com/articles/1747-taking-an-itemized-deduction-for-job-expenses.html
http://www.bankrate.com/finance/money-guides/business-expenses-that-benefit-you.aspx
http://www.hrblock.com/taxes/tax_tips/tax_planning/employment.html

But of course, go to the source:

http://www.irs.gov/publications/p529/ar02.html#en_US_publink100026912

From publication 529:

> You can deduct certain expenses as
>   miscellaneous itemized deductions on
>   Schedule A (Form 1040 or Form 1040NR).
>   You can claim the amount of expenses
>   that is more than 2% of your adjusted
>   gross income. You figure your
>   deduction on Schedule A by subtracting
>   2% of your adjusted gross income from
>   the total amount of these expenses.
>   Your adjusted gross income is the
>   amount on Form 1040, line 38, or Form
>   1040NR, line 36.

I hope that helps.  Happy deducting!